# Angular4 Material Open Dialog with Reference

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material2

There is a way to open a Angular / Material Dialog using a reference string, something like this:

```
this.dialog.open('randomComponent', {data: {element}});
```

The component must by define on the app.component.ts, this is kinda obvious

the app.component should be something like

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    randomComponent
    ],
    imports: [
     ...
    ]
  ],
  entryComponents: [
     randomComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i wanna open a dialog using a string reference of the component

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, is it not possible to do that? something like `this.dialogRef.open()` ???